# How to implement Chat with base knowledge data using Pinecone + Langchain + Node.js?

Tags: node.js, embedding, openai-api, langchain

I am making the chatbot that answers to user's question based on user's provided information.
When user uploads his data (Markdown, PDF, TXT, etc), the chatbot splits the data to the small chunks and convert it to vector data using OpenAI Embeddings and store it to pinecone.
And when user asks something, the chatbot will search the best similar chunk using OpenAI Embeddings and get the ChatGPT response using some custom prompt based on the searched context.

So, it can answer with user's provided data.
But that is not working well.
I implemented all features but when user ask something, the chatbot searches the 1 best similar data so it can't answer with enough data.
How can I solve this problem?

I referred some tutorials and videos but I can't find the solution.
[GPT-4 & LangChain Tutorial: How to Chat with A 56-Pages of PDF](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ih9PBGVVOO4)

```
import { Request, Response } from "express";
import asyncHandler from 'express-async-handler';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
import { MarkdownTextSplitter } from "langchain/text_splitter";
import { PineconeClient } from '@pinecone-database/pinecone';
import { OpenAIEmbeddings } from 'langchain/embeddings/openai';
import { ChatOpenAI } from "langchain/chat_models/openai";
import { PineconeStore } from 'langchain/vectorstores/pinecone';
import { HumanChatMessage, SystemChatMessage } from "langchain/schema";
import { PromptTemplate } from "langchain";

/**
 * @method POST
 * @params role: rold ID, docText: Document Content, model: Embedding Model
 * @description Splite Markdown&HTML Document and generate embeddings from OpenAI
 */
export const generateEmbeddings = asyncHandler(
  async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    const role: string = req.body.role as string;
    const docText: string = req.body.docText as string;
    // Get Unique id for document
    const documentId: string = uuidv4();

    const pinecone = new PineconeClient();
    const pineconeAPIKey: string = process.env.PINECONE_API_KEY ?? '';
    await pinecone.init({
      environment: process.env.PINECONE_ENVIRONMENT ?? '',
      apiKey: pineconeAPIKey,
    });

    try {
      const splitter = new MarkdownTextSplitter();

      const output = await splitter.createDocuments([docText], [{
        doc: documentId,
        role: role
      }]);

      console.log('creating vector store...');
      // Create and store the embeddings in the vectorStore
      const embeddings = new OpenAIEmbeddings();
      const index = pinecone.Index(process.env.PINECONE_INDEX ?? '');
      const dbConfig = {
        pineconeIndex: index,
        namespace: process.env.PINECONE_NAMESPACE ?? '',
        textKey: 'markdown',
      };

      const response = await PineconeStore.fromDocuments(output, embeddings, dbConfig);
      // res.json({docId: documentId}); 
      res.json(response)
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error processing markdown uploading:', error);
      res.status(500).send('An error occurred while processing the file upload.');
    }
  }
);

/**
 * @method POST
 * @params role, message, embeddingModel, ranking
 * @middleware validations/searchEmbedding
 * @desc
 */
export const searchSimilarDocument = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {

  const role: string = req.body.role as string;
  const query: string = req.body.query as string;
  const ranking: number = (req.body.ranking as number) || 1;

  const client = new PineconeClient();
  await client.init({
    apiKey: process.env.PINECONE_API_KEY ?? '',
    environment: process.env.PINECONE_ENVIRONMENT ?? '',
  });

  const pineconeIndex = client.Index(process.env.PINECONE_INDEX ?? '');
  const vectorStore = await PineconeStore.fromExistingIndex(
    new OpenAIEmbeddings(),
    { 
      pineconeIndex: pineconeIndex,
      namespace: process.env.PINECONE_NAMESPACE ?? '',
      textKey: 'markdown'
    }
  );

  try {
    const results = await vectorStore.similaritySearch(query, ranking, {
      role: role,
    });
    const chat = new ChatOpenAI({ temperature: 0 });

    const response = await chat.call([
      new SystemChatMessage(
        `We have provided context information below:\n
        ---------------------/\n
        ${results[0].pageContent}
        ---------------------/\n
        Given this information, Please answer my question in the same language that I used to ask you.`
      ),
      new HumanChatMessage(query),
    ]);

    res.json(response);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Query Error: ' + err)
  }
};
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You have the `k` parameter in documentation: number of source documents returned. see https://js.langchain.com/docs/modules/indexes/vector_stores/